# CascadeMode StopOnFirstFailure doesn't work

Tags: fluentvalidation

```
public class Validator : AbstractValidator<Query>
        {
            public Validator()
            {
                CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;

                RuleFor(x => x.A).NotEmpty();
                RuleFor(x => x.B).NotEmpty();
                RuleFor(x => x).MustAsync(...);
            }
        }
```

I'like to construct validator which dones't call `MustAsync` when above rules are not met. Unfortunately settings `CascadeMode` to `StopOnFirstFailure`  in validator doesn't do the work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by the author

> That's the correct behaviour - CascadeMode only affects validators
>   within the same rule chain. Independent calls to RuleFor are separate,
>   and not dependent on the success or failure of other rules.

See [this](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/171).

So it would apply for this case

```
Rulefor(x => x.A)
.NotEmpty()
.Length(10);
```

=> the `Length` validation would only be applied if `A` is not empty.

So you'll have to use a `When` extension in your `MustAsync` rule, checking if `A` and `B` are not empty (or an `if` around this rule).

Comment: i dont understend the purpose of "StopOnFirstFailure" the documentation say "When a rule fails, validation is stopped and all other rules in the chain will not be executed."

Comment: @juancarlospeñacabrera You might have a rule that "crashes" if the previous rule is broken (after a NotNull() for example). Or you have one message for each rule in chain, and don't want to show 10 error messages for the same property.